# Using all cases of union type F#

Tags: f#

This is very linked to the question here [How to enumerate an enum/type in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181956/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-type-in-f). I define a union type and then I need to use all the possible cases of the type in static method. For example:

```
type Interests =
| Music 
| Books
| Movies
    with 
        static member GetValue( this) = match this with 
                                         | Music  -> 0
                                         | Books -> 5
                                         | Movies -> 0
        static member GetSeqValues() = allCases|>Seq.map(GetValue)
```

How do I get allCases ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `FSharpType.GetUnionCases()` from `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` to get all cases of a discriminated union. In your example, it would look like this:

```
type Interests = 
   | Music  
   | Books 
   | Movies
   static member GetValue(this) = (...)
   static member GetSeqValues() = 
     // Get all cases of the union
     let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<Interests>)
     [ for c in cases do 
         // Create value for each case (assuming it has no arguments)
         let interest = FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, [| |]) :?> Interests
         yield GetValue(interest) ]
```

However, the problem is that you may not be able to create instances to pass to your `GetValue` member, because some cases may have arguments (when calling `MakeUnion` you have to pass it an array of arguments and I used just an empty array). For example if you had:

```
type Sample =
 | A of int
 | B of bool
```

Comment: so Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<Interests>) returns a seq of UnionCaseInfo, from which I cant seem to get a seq of Interests

Comment: @jlezard: I added more information (I had to run away for a few minutes.. :-))

Answer (score 0):

I made [an expansion of Tomas' work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IYOH3I) that handles making any type of FSharp Union (handles properties of the union case)
as long as you provide it the logic for what to do with non-union children.

```
let rec getAllDUCases fNonUnionArg t : obj list =
    let getAllDUCases = getAllDUCases fNonUnionArg
    // taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497058/lazy-cartesian-product-of-multiple-sequences-sequence-of-sequences
    let cartesian_product2 sequences = 
        let step acc sequence = seq {
            for x in acc do
            for y in sequence do
            yield seq { yield! x; yield y}}
        Seq.fold step (Seq.singleton Seq.empty) sequences

    let makeCaseTypes (fUnion:Type-> obj list) (fNonUnionArg:Type -> obj) (uc: UnionCaseInfo) : UnionCaseInfo*(obj list list) =
        let constructorArgs = 
            uc.GetFields() 
            |> Seq.map (fun f -> 
                if FSharpType.IsUnion f.PropertyType then 
                    let childTypes = fUnion f.PropertyType 
                    if 
                        childTypes
                        |> Seq.exists (fun ct -> FSharpType.IsUnion (ct.GetType()) |> not) then
                            failwithf "fUnion returned a bad type in list %A" childTypes
                    childTypes
                else [ fNonUnionArg f.PropertyType] )
            |> List.ofSeq
        let allCombinationsOfFieldPossibles = 
            cartesian_product2 constructorArgs
            |> Seq.map List.ofSeq
            |> List.ofSeq
        uc, allCombinationsOfFieldPossibles
    // with help from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4470670/57883
    let result =
        FSharpType.GetUnionCases t
        |> Seq.map (makeCaseTypes getAllDUCases fNonUnionArg)
        |> List.ofSeq
    let result = 
        result
        |> Seq.map (fun (uc,allFieldComboCases) -> allFieldComboCases |> Seq.map (fun args-> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(uc,args |> Array.ofList)))
        |> Seq.collect id
        |> Seq.map box
        |> List.ofSeq
    result
```