# How to iterate over an Enum, and cast the obj

Tags: enums, f#, ienumerable

[How to enumerate an enum/type in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181956/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-type-in-f) tells us how to get an enumerator for a .Net enum type in F#:

Use: `Enum.GetValues(typeof<MyType>)`

However, when I put that into use I found a limitation. I can work around that limitation, but I am looking for a better way.

The problem is that the solution returns a .Net Array of Objects, but to use it we need to cast it, and that casting is unwieldy for iteration.

```
type Colors =
| Red = 0
| Blue = 1
| Green = 2

// Strongly typed function, to show the 'obj' in real use
let isFavorite color = color = Colors.Green

// Iterate over the Enum (Colors)
for color in Enum.GetValues(typeof<Colors>) do
    printfn "Color %A. Is Favorite -> %b" color (isFavorite color)  // <-- Need to cast
```

The `(IsFavorite color)` raises a type conflict between `Colors` (expected) and `obj` (actual)

This is easily fixed:

```
for obj in Enum.GetValues(typeof<Colors>) do
    printfn "Color %A. Is Favorite -> %b" obj (isFavorite (unbox<Colors> obj))
```

But, what if one needs that `(unbox<Colors> obj)` in several places?

A local `let color = ...` will suffice, but, ideally, we would use an enumerable-expression which returns a `seq<Colors>`.

I have been able to build that expression, but it is: a. difficult to build, and b. long winded.

```
let colorsSeq = 
     Seq.cast (Enum.GetValues(typeof<Colors>)) 
     |> Seq.map (fun o -> unbox<Colors> o)

for color in colorsSeq do
    printfn "Color %A. Is Favorite -> %b" color (isFavorite color)
```

Is there a better expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would seem to be about the simplest possible version:

```
let t : Colors seq = unbox (Enum.GetValues(typeof<Colors>))
```

Comment: This is simple enough to put straight into the for loop: `for color in (Enum.GetValues(typeof<Colors>)) |> unbox do ...`. The type of `unbox` here is unclear. Intellisense infers `obj -> 'T`, however it is clearly unboxing the array, element by element, and somehow inferring the type of the result.

Comment: I think that the `unbox` uses the fact that the returned type from `GetValues` implements `Ienumerable<'t>`

Comment: @JohnPalmer. The returned type from `GetValues` does not really implement `IEnumerable<'T>`, it implements `IEnumerable` only. You cannot upcast it to `Colors seq` directly, you'd need to downcast to a type wbich does first. That happens to be the F# _array type_,
which is somewhat special, since it behaves as it were "an instantiation of a fictitious type definition System.Array<ty>" (§5.1.4 spec).
Whatever goes on under the hood seems to be more than your explanation suggests.

Comment: @kaefer - are you sure - this seems to suggest that the return value does actually implement the interface - `printfn "%A" ((Enum.GetValues(typeof<Colors>).GetType() :?> System.Reflection.TypeInfo).ImplementedInterfaces);;` - also see the notes in the remarks here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JohnPalmer. No, I'm not. Just noticing that your quote doesn't specify if those hidden interfaces are a CLI feature or a language feature.
If the latter case, then F# has a similar feature, one that is at work when you're testing for the presence of such an interface. Consider `(Enum.GetValues typeof<Colors>).GetType().Name`, which gives `"Colors[]"`.

Comment: @kaefer The interface implementation is not language-specific.  The documentation cited is .NET Framework documentation, not C# documentation.  All those reflection members (`GetType` and `ImplementedInterfaces`) behave the same regardless of the language from which they are called.

Answer (score 6):

`Enum.GetValues` is an old BCL API, so there's nothing much you can do about it... I don't think you can get what you want in a *significantly* more concise way than what you already have, but you *can* reduce it a bit:

```
let colorsSeq = Enum.GetValues(typeof<Colors>) |> Seq.cast<Colors>
```

If you need to do something like this a lot, you could consider packaging it in a generic function:

```
module Enum = 
    let values<'a> = Enum.GetValues(typeof<'a>) |> Seq.cast<'a>
```

Which would enable you to use it like this:

```
for color in Enum.values<Colors> do
    printfn "Color %A. Is Favorite -> %b" color (isFavorite color)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to `map unbox<'a>`: you can directly `Seq.cast<'a>`.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you - I've now corrected my answer :)

Comment: Thanks Mark. That is a significant improvement, and also avoids the (apparently) special use of `unbox`.

Comment: Thankyou, also, Mark, for the explanation that the problem originates from the untyped, BCL Enum.GetValues

Comment: @StephenHosking the "unbox" use is not special -- it's simply casting a `Colors[]` instance from a `System.Object` reference to an `IEnumerable<Colors>` reference.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest generic expression would be the casting (or unboxing) to the underlying type `'T[]`. Thus

```
module Enum =
    open System
    let cases<'T when 'T :> Enum> = Enum.GetValues typeof<'T> :?> 'T[]
```

which translates to C# as

```
public static class Enum
{
    public static T[] cases<T>() where T : Enum
    {
        return (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Plugged into the code in the question it gives this output:

```
type Colors =
| Red = 0
| Blue = 1
| Green = 2
let isFavorite color = color = Colors.Green

for color in Enum.cases<Colors> do
    printfn "Color %A. Is Favorite -> %b" color (isFavorite color)

//Color Red. Is Favorite -> false
//Color Blue. Is Favorite -> false
//Color Green. Is Favorite -> true
```

Comment: This can also go straight into the `for` loop, as follows: `Enum.GetValues typeof<Colors> :?> Colors[]`. I now favor this as the answer, because it is just a type cast on the primitive. However, I'll wait a while before changing my accepted answer - and consider any comments. As this question has raised some discussion, of a detailed technical nature, I'll probably wait a few days.